# Cannot save data to realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I cannot seem to save data to realm in Swift!

In one of my classes I have the following:

```
func getDeviceIdAndPersist(){
 print("getDeviceIdAndPersist")
 let realm = try! Realm()
 let realmWallet = RealmWallet()
 let realmResults = realm.objects(RealmWallet.self)
 for results in realmResults {
   guard results.deviceId != nil else {
     realmWallet.deviceId = NSUUID().UUIDString
     try! realm.write() {
       realm.add(realmWallet, update: true)
     }
    return
   }
 }
}
```

And it does not seem to save the data! I have code similar to this throughout my application and its saving data but this isn't!

Also I'm having trouble trying to persist my data, after i launch the application the data is stored using realm (which i can verify using the realm browser). However, once I re-launch the application the data no longer exists in realm! Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the data would not be persisted?

**EDIT 1**

Here is my realm class

```
class RealmWallet: Object {
  dynamic var publicKey = NSData()
  dynamic var preferredAddress = ""
  dynamic var id = 0
  let walletAddresses = List<Addresses>()
  dynamic var fee: NSNumber = 0.0
  dynamic var deviceId: String? = nil
  dynamic var tempPreTax: String? = nil
  dynamic var portalToken: String? = nil
  let walletHasBackup = RealmOptional<Bool>()
  let alreadyAskedForBluetooth = RealmOptional<Bool>()
  let insecureMailSent = RealmOptional<Bool>()
  let cameraAccessGranted = RealmOptional<Bool>()
  let idNowSuccess = RealmOptional<Bool>()
  dynamic var marketInfos = NSData()

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
  return "id"
 }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

The NSUUID isn't the only data which I cannot save, the following is another example of data which I cannot seem to save using Realm:

```
onboardingModal!.bluetoothPressed = {() -> Void in
 print("after onboardingModal")
  self.cbManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
  print("REALM")
  let realm = try! Realm()

  do {
    try! realm.write {
      print("IN WRITE")
      self.realmWallet.alreadyAskedForBluetooth.value = true
      realm.add(self.realmWallet, update: true)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please add your `RealmWallet` code class, perhaps the class has the `dynamic` for its variables

Comment: Added the class, and it does! Should it not have dynamic then?

Comment: Are you modifying the default configuration (`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`) at all? Also, do you have any code in your app to remove on-disk files, e.g. at startup?

Comment: Nope im not touching the configuration of realm at all! And nope theres no code that removes anything thats locally stored! This is become really frustrating now, realm is not working at all like i would expect it to! I've found that if i comment out the only write call that actually adds data to realm then this allows other functions to add data instead, could this mean its to do with a threading issue or something? I can sort of add data to different records at the same time but i need all the data to be under one record!

Comment: There's nothing in your code that jumps out at me as being incorrect. If you Realm isn't behaving as you think it should, please file an issue at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new with full steps to reproduce

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. In my realm class i was missing  @objc dynamic in front of stored properties. So added it like below. Then it worked for me.

```
 @objc dynamic var address: Addres!
 @objc dynamic var checklist: Checklist!
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Results count is 0, it will not enter your for loop.
Try this instead.

```
func getDeviceIdAndPersist() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let realmResults = realm.objects(RealmWallet.self)
    guard results.count > 0 else {
        let realmWallet = RealmWallet()
        realmWallet.deviceId = NSUUID().UUIDString
        try! realm.write() {
          realm.add(realmWallet, update: true)
        }
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't save for some reason!